# How do I generate a WorldWind importable image file with a transparent background using an SLD file with PointSymbolizers on Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wms, java, sld, worldwind

I've been tasked with visualizing a few types of metoc data onto Worldwind based on .grib files. I'm VERY new to the GIS world and I'm just beginning to figure out how a lot of these pieces go together (so expect more questions from me!)

I just learned how to use an SLD to generate windbarbs in Geoserver. The windbarbs themselves look correct and get plotted in Worldwind correctly (in the right location) when I download a geotiff off Geoserver. However question #1 is how do I generate an image file that I can import into WorldWind with a transparent background? I think i read that tiffs don't support transparency, so should I use a different format? Which one? and how do I configure my layer in geoserver or edit my SLD to produce a transparent background?

I tried downloading jpeg, png, etc.. from Geoserver but the only format that produces an image is any tiff format.

Here's a link to my SLD file: http://pastebin.com/km05xVAR

Here's the variable info from the grib2 file I'm using (v-component obviously identical):

```
float u-component_of_wind_surface(time=61, lat=29, lon=29);
  :long_name = "u-component of wind @ Ground or water surface";
  :units = "m/s";
  :abbreviation = "UGRD";
  :missing_value = NaNf; // float
  :grid_mapping = "LatLon_Projection";
  :coordinates = "reftime time lat lon";
  :Grib_Variable_Id = "VAR_0-2-2_L1";
  :Grib2_Parameter = 0, 2, 2; // int
  :Grib2_Parameter_Discipline = "Meteorological products";
  :Grib2_Parameter_Category = "Momentum";
  :Grib2_Parameter_Name = "u-component of wind";
  :Grib2_Level_Type = "Ground or water surface";
  :Grib2_Generating_Process_Type = "Forecast";
```

If you're curious, here's the entire data dump of u/v data: http://pastebin.com/sJf61EYk

Here's what I have in Worldwind right now:

[image: Worldwind output]

Comment: Aftering digging around I tried a workaround to just add transparency to the BufferedImage in Java. Thanks to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/665483

It kind of works but I don't think it's an acceptable solution since I don't want want to have to manually filter every image i import into World Wind.  http://i.imgur.com/ANhqKQ8.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with PointPlacemark, here is part of my code block;

```
public void insertGeoPin(Position selectedPosition, Color pointColor) {
        System.out.println("Trying to Insert Symbol on Simulation");
        this.pointPlacemark = new PointPlacemark(selectedPosition);
        this.pointPlacemark.setLabelText("P-" + this.counter + "(" + getShortString(selectedPosition) + ")");
        this.pointPlacemark.setValue(AVKey.DISPLAY_NAME, "Clamp to ground, Label, Semi-transparent, Audio icon");
        this.pointPlacemark.setLineEnabled(false);
        this.pointPlacemark.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.CLAMP_TO_GROUND);
        PointPlacemarkAttributes pointPlacemarkAttributes = new PointPlacemarkAttributes();
        pointPlacemarkAttributes.setImageAddress("res/images/tank.gif");
        pointPlacemarkAttributes.setScale(0.2);
        pointPlacemarkAttributes.setAntiAliasHint(Polyline.ANTIALIAS_DONT_CARE);
        pointPlacemarkAttributes.setImageColor(pointColor);
```

And here is the screenshot of tank with transparent background.
[image]